# Why is JSON.parse only parsing the first and last keys in the hash?

Tags: ruby, json, hashmap

I receive an array that is formatted like this

```
{\"message\":\"{\\\"_id\\\":\\\"9E7A;10000000266_UserScreensConfig\\\",\\\"userDefinedScreens\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":\\\"documents\\\"},{\\\"appLeft\\\":\\\"patientInfo\\\",\\\"appletHeader\\\":\\\"navigation\\\",\\\"applets\\\":[{\\\"dataCol\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"dataMaxSizeX\\\":\\\"8\\\",\\\"dataMaxSizeY\\\":\\\"12\\\",\\\"dataMinSizeX\\\":\\\"4\\\",\\\"dataMinSizeY\\\":\\\"3\\\",\\\"dataRow\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"dataSizeX\\\":\\\"8\\\",\\\"dataSizeY\\\":\\\"6\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"allergy_grid\\\",\\\"instanceId\\\":\\\"applet-1\\\",\\\"maximizeScreen\\\":\\\"allergy-grid-full\\\",\\\"region\\\":\\\"applet-1\\\",\\\"showInUDWSelection\\\":true,\\\"title\\\":\\\"Allergies\\\",\\\"viewType\\\":\\\"expanded\\\"}],\\\"contentRegionLayout\\\":\\\"gridster\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"user-defined-workspace-1\\\",\\\"userDefinedScreen\\\":true}],\\\"userScreensConfig\\\":{\\\"screens\\\":[{\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"cover-sheet\\\",\\\"predefined\\\":true,\\\"routeName\\\":\\\"cover-sheet\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Coversheet\\\"},{\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"news-feed\\\",\\\"predefined\\\":true,\\\"routeName\\\":\\\"news-feed\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Timeline\\\"},{\\\"defaultScreen\\\":true,\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"overview\\\",\\\"predefined\\\":true,\\\"routeName\\\":\\\"overview\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Overview\\\"},{\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"medication-review\\\",\\\"predefined\\\":true,\\\"routeName\\\":\\\"medication-review\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Meds Review\\\"},{\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"documents\\\",\\\"predefined\\\":true,\\\"routeName\\\":\\\"documents-list\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Documents\\\"},{\\\"author\\\":\\\"PANORAMA USER\\\",\\\"defaultScreen\\\":false,\\\"fileName\\\":\\\"NewUserScreen\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"user-defined-workspace-1\\\",\\\"routeName\\\":\\\"user-defined-workspace-1\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"User Defined Workspace 1\\\"}]},\\\"userDefinedFilters\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":\\\"user-defined-workspace-1\\\",\\\"applets\\\":[{\\\"instanceId\\\":\\\"applet-1\\\",\\\"filters\\\":[\\\"CHOCOLATE\\\"]}]}]}\",\"status\":200}
```

I send it through JSON.parse and I receive this

```
{\"message\"=>\"{\\\"_id\\\":\\\"9E7A;10000000266_UserScreensConfig\\\",\\\"userDefinedScreens\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":\\\"documents\\\"},{\\\"appLeft\\\":\\\"patientInfo\\\",\\\"appletHeader\\\":\\\"navigation\\\",\\\"applets\\\":[{\\\"dataCol\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"dataMaxSizeX\\\":\\\"8\\\",\\\"dataMaxSizeY\\\":\\\"12\\\",\\\"dataMinSizeX\\\":\\\"4\\\",\\\"dataMinSizeY\\\":\\\"3\\\",\\\"dataRow\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"dataSizeX\\\":\\\"8\\\",\\\"dataSizeY\\\":\\\"6\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"allergy_grid\\\",\\\"instanceId\\\":\\\"applet-1\\\",\\\"maximizeScreen\\\":\\\"allergy-grid-full\\\",\\\"region\\\":\\\"applet-1\\\",\\\"showInUDWSelection\\\":true,\\\"title\\\":\\\"Allergies\\\",\\\"viewType\\\":\\\"expanded\\\"}],\\\"contentRegionLayout\\\":\\\"gridster\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"user-defined-workspace-1\\\",\\\"userDefinedScreen\\\":true}],\\\"userScreensConfig\\\":{\\\"screens\\\":[{\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"cover-sheet\\\",\\\"predefined\\\":true,\\\"routeName\\\":\\\"cover-sheet\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Coversheet\\\"},{\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"news-feed\\\",\\\"predefined\\\":true,\\\"routeName\\\":\\\"news-feed\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Timeline\\\"},{\\\"defaultScreen\\\":true,\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"overview\\\",\\\"predefined\\\":true,\\\"routeName\\\":\\\"overview\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Overview\\\"},{\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"medication-review\\\",\\\"predefined\\\":true,\\\"routeName\\\":\\\"medication-review\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Meds Review\\\"},{\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"documents\\\",\\\"predefined\\\":true,\\\"routeName\\\":\\\"documents-list\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Documents\\\"},{\\\"author\\\":\\\"PANORAMA USER\\\",\\\"defaultScreen\\\":false,\\\"fileName\\\":\\\"NewUserScreen\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"user-defined-workspace-1\\\",\\\"routeName\\\":\\\"user-defined-workspace-1\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"User Defined Workspace 1\\\"}]},\\\"userDefinedFilters\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":\\\"user-defined-workspace-1\\\",\\\"applets\\\":[{\\\"instanceId\\\":\\\"applet-1\\\",\\\"filters\\\":[\\\"CHOCOLATE\\\"]}]}]}\", \"status\"=>200}
```

Only the first and the last keys seem formatted. The rest of the semi-colons are kept as ":" instead of being converted to "=>". Why is this happening?

Comment: Are those extra back-slashes in the middle common? I feel like that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Jkeuhlen's comment is correct I believe. Are you sure the response is exactly formatted the way you typed it? When I call JSON.parse on your array hash I get

```
{"message"=>"{\"_id\":\"9E7A;10000000266_UserScreensConfig\",\"userDefinedScreens\":[{\"id\":\"documents\"},{\"appLeft\":\"patientInfo\",\"appletHeader\":\"navigation\",\"applets\":[{\"dataCol\":\"2\",\"dataMaxSizeX\":\"8\",\"dataMaxSizeY\":\"12\",\"dataMinSizeX\":\"4\",\"dataMinSizeY\":\"3\",\"dataRow\":\"1\",\"dataSizeX\":\"8\",\"dataSizeY\":\"6\",\"id\":\"allergy_grid\",\"instanceId\":\"applet-1\",\"maximizeScreen\":\"allergy-grid-full\",\"region\":\"applet-1\",\"showInUDWSelection\":true,\"title\":\"Allergies\",\"viewType\":\"expanded\"}],\"contentRegionLayout\":\"gridster\",\"id\":\"user-defined-workspace-1\",\"userDefinedScreen\":true}],\"userScreensConfig\":{\"screens\":[{\"description\":\"\",\"id\":\"cover-sheet\",\"predefined\":true,\"routeName\":\"cover-sheet\",\"title\":\"Coversheet\"},{\"description\":\"\",\"id\":\"news-feed\",\"predefined\":true,\"routeName\":\"news-feed\",\"title\":\"Timeline\"},{\"defaultScreen\":true,\"description\":\"\",\"id\":\"overview\",\"predefined\":true,\"routeName\":\"overview\",\"title\":\"Overview\"},{\"description\":\"\",\"id\":\"medication-review\",\"predefined\":true,\"routeName\":\"medication-review\",\"title\":\"Meds Review\"},{\"description\":\"\",\"id\":\"documents\",\"predefined\":true,\"routeName\":\"documents-list\",\"title\":\"Documents\"},{\"author\":\"PANORAMA USER\",\"defaultScreen\":false,\"fileName\":\"NewUserScreen\",\"id\":\"user-defined-workspace-1\",\"routeName\":\"user-defined-workspace-1\",\"title\":\"User Defined Workspace 1\"}]},\"userDefinedFilters\":[{\"id\":\"user-defined-workspace-1\",\"applets\":[{\"instanceId\":\"applet-1\",\"filters\":[\"CHOCOLATE\"]}]}]}", "status"=>200}
```

Notice the extra back slashes are gone, your first JSON.parse is parsing the inner value mapped by "message" into a another string, which can now be parsed into the form that you probably wanted it.

This should convert the rest of the inner hash pointed to by "message"

```
 x = JSON.parse(yourArray)
 JSON.parse(x["message"])
```